# How to install virtualbox on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded the Ubuntu version from this link: 
virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Ubuntu 13.04 ("Raring Ringtail") / 13.10 ("Saucy Salamander") / 14.04 ("Trusty Tahr") 64bit
download.virtualbox .org/virtualbox/4.3.18 virtualbox- .3_4.3.18-96516~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb

2. I installed by terminal:

   > wget -q https:// virtualbox .org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo
   >   apt-key add -

Since it didn't work, I tried something else.

1. I downloaded the Windows version: virtualbox .org/wiki/Downloads
   download.virtualbox .org/virtualbox/4.3.18/VirtualBox-4.3.18-96516-Win.exe
2. I installed it by using "Wine", and received this error:

   > Error window: SUPR3HardenedMain Effective UID is not root (euid=1000
   >   egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000) (rc=-10) Please try reinstalling
   >   VirtualBox.

Any other way to do it? I can't find why is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you install the package with:

```
sudo dpkg --install virtualbox-4.3_4.3.18-96516~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb
```

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive virtualbox-4.3_4.3.18-96516~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-4.3_4.3.18-96516~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb

Comment: `cd` to the folder to which you downloaded the virtualbox package prior to installation.

Comment: smooth answer! thanks please i thinks for newbies like me this informations is value, don't vote it down! thanks

Comment: Thanks to you for marking this answer. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can install virtual box from the ubuntu software center or

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt
```

Comment: smooth answer. thanks